# How to run multi-thread programs in rocket-chip?

Tags: multithreading, riscv, rocket-chip

I am trying to run multi-thread programs/benchmark in a [rocket-chip](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/) SoC I generated from [chipyard](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard).
I generated the TutorialConfig SoC given in https://fires.im/isca22-slides-pdf/03_building_custom_socs.pdf, which consists of a Rocket core and a BOOM core.

To check whether I can run a multi-threaded program in this configuration, I compiled the mt-matmul benchmark in riscv-tests after changing the number of cores in crt.S file.

I ran it using the following command:

```
make CONFIG=TutorialStarterConfig run-binary BINARY=riscv-tests/benchmarks/mt-matmul.riscv
```

In the output trace, I can only see 'C0' at the beginning of each line, I am assuming I should see 'C1' if the program was executed in a second core.

Is this the correct way to run multi-threaded programs with RocketChip SoCs?
Do I need to change anything else in the programs or in the SoC?